# Is #if preprocessor macro "running" #ifdef behind the scenes in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macros, c-preprocessor

If I create a preprocessor macro named `DEBUG` for the `Debug` configuration of a project's target with the value `1`, and not for the `Release` configuration, I find that using

```
#if DEBUG
...
#endif
```

compiles for `Release` builds too.

Firstly, is it checking if `DEBUG` is defined and **after** that if it evaluates to `true`? If yes, is it ok (or recommended) to use it this way instead of

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #if DEBUG
    ...
    #endif
#endif
```

?

Comment: `#if DEBUG` should only be true of `DEBUG` is defined and it has a non-zero value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not recommended to use `#if VARIABLE` without checking that `VARIABLE` has been defined.

When `#if` evaluates the expression, it does the following:

1. It expands all macros in the expression (which means that an symbol which has not been `#define`d will be unchanged.)
2. It parses the result as an integer arithmetic expression, replacing any identifier with the integer 0.

So if `DEBUG` has not been `#define`d as a macro,

```
#if DEBUG
```

will be the same as

```
#if 0
```

which will also have the same effect as `#ifdef DEBUG`.

If you define `DEBUG` on the command-line with `-DDEBUG`, then there is an implicit

```
#define DEBUG 1
```

before the file is preprocessed, with the result that

```
#if DEBUG
```

is the same as

```
#if 1
```

which is also the same as `#ifdef DEBUG`.

**However**. If you did the following:

```
#define DEBUG
#if DEBUG
//  ... stuff
#endif
```

the the `#if` will expand to:

```
#if
```

and you'll get an error message:

```
file.m:2:6: error: #if with no expression
```

As a result, it is unwise to use `#if VARIABLE`, unless you know for sure that `VARIABLE` has been defined as an integer.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the detailed answer! But, as @Jody Hagins mentioned, Xcode by default provides the preprocessor macro `DEBUG=1` for the `Debug` configuration and none for the `Release configuration`. So, for this case, is it still wrong to use `#if DEBUG` instead of `#ifdef DEBUG`?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei: On the whole, it's better to use `#ifdef DEBUG`. On XCode it may make no difference, but someday you might want to compile the code in a different environment.

Answer (score 2):

Modern Xcode already provides a definition for DEBUG when building in debug mode.

[image]

The difference between `#ifdef DEBUG` and `#if DEBUG` is that `#ifdef DEBUG` will be true when the symbol is defined, no matter what value has been defined.

Thus, `#define DEBUG=0` will be true for `#ifdef DEBUG` because it has a defined value (it will also be true for `#define DEBUG` for the same reason).

However, `#if DEBUG` will only be true if `DEBUG` has been defined with a non-zero value.

Comment: I wanted to say that but I wasn't sure if it is indeed a default behavior or the previous developer on the project added it.

Comment: So the short answer is `Yes`, it does check if the macro is defined and it doesn't crashes the build if it's not defined like I thought, right?

Comment: `#if DEBUG` will simply return `false` if `DEBUG` isn't defined or its value is zero. It won't crash if not defined.